# PHP While Loop Resolve

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I am having a bit of trouble resolving things in a PHP while loop. Basically I have an array in this form (easier to represent in JSON for brevity)

```
{
    "node2": {
        "rowid": "2",
        "label": "Eco-Lights - Compact Fluorescent Lamps (CFL)",
        "slug": "eco-lights-compact-fluorescent-lamps-cfl",
        "prefix": "/categories",
        "parent": "55",
        "path": null,
        "weight": "100",
        "featured": "0",
        "active": "0"
    },
    "node3": {
        "rowid": "3",
        "label": "Light Movers, Hangers and Accessories",
        "slug": "light-movers-hangers-and-accessories",
        "prefix": "/categories",
        "parent": "59",
        "path": null,
        "weight": "100",
        "featured": "0",
        "active": "0"
    }
}
```

This array is about 150 elements give or take a few. The key of the node is simply "node"+rowid for ease of lookup (in the next part)

What I am trying to do is take any node and go right up until its parent is zero (i/e has no parents) and on each iteration grab the label and slug of the parent element.

So far I have done this using a while loop as below. `$this->categories` is the array as above. The trouble is that the loop is incorrect and it's hitting 4gb of memory and doing around 5,000 loops for an array of 150 elements with roughly one parent each so it should be something less than 500 iterations.

```
public function ResolveCategoryUrl($id) {
    $element=$element=$this->categories['node'.$id];
    $parent=$element['parent'];
    while(1) {
        $prev=$element;
        $element=$this->categories['node'.$element['parent']];
        $parts[]=$element['slug'];
        $breadcrumbs[]=['label'=>$element['label'],'url'=>$element['prefix'].$element['path'].$element['data']['url_postfix']];
        $parent=$element['parent'];
        if($parent<=1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return [
        'path'=>array_reverse($parts),
        'breadcrumbs'=>$breadcrumbs
    ];
}
```

I cannot figure out how to tell PHP to take an element and work backward up to its parent until `parent = 0` then return what I want from the function.

Sorry if the explanation is difficult, I have no other way to explain it!

Comment: are you sure that, for the given id, your data will bring you back to the element with id 0? at first look the code seems right and if the problem is on data we can't do anything about it

Comment: There is no element with id=0, It's purposely removed from the array in the beginning.

Comment: have you thought of recursion?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a basic reverse tree search (starting at a leaf node and working back up to the root).  This is accomplished easily when using recursion. Something along these lines is probably what you're looking for:

```
function visitNode($nodeNum, $output = [])
{
    $output[] = $nodeNum;
    $element = $this->categories['node' . $nodeNum];
    $parent = $element['parent'];

    // Recursive case: keep searching until you're at the parent
    if($parent != 0) {
        return visitNode($parent, $output);
    }

    // Base Case
    return $output;
}
```

The output of this function will be an array of your ids representing the chain of nodes visited on the search from your leaf node to its parent. The output of calling this on a parent node will be an array with a single entry.

You may need to put in another case to ensure that the category `node + $nodeNum` actually exists, but it may make more sense for that to be elsewhere.

**Update**

To use this function to solve your particular problem and build the breadcrumbs (getting the specific output you require):

```
$path = [];
$breadcrumbs = [];
$myStartNode = '3';
$pathIds = array_reverse(visitNode($myStartNode));
foreach($pathIds as $pathId) {
    $element = $this->categories[$pathId];
    $path[] = $element->slug;
    $breadcrumbs[] = [
        'label' => $element['label'],
         'url' => $element['prefix'].$element['path'].$element['data']['url_postfix']
    ];
}

return [ 'path' => $path, 'breadcrumbs' => $breadcrumbs ];
```

The `visitNode` function above was mentioned solely to try to help solve the issue I believe that you're having difficulty with. Also, it's probably best to keep that logic outside what you're trying to do because you may be required to perform that same sort of tree traversal in another context that requires different output.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how it builds up $parts from my original question. The reason of the function is to slowly work it's way up until the parent = 0, adding each path and breadcrumb on its way so eventually there is a full path as in /one/two/three (when imploded with "/" of course!)

Comment: Updated answer, once you have the ids of the _path_ to the parent, you should be able to build up the output you need however you want.

Comment: That edit is brilliant thanks but for some reason I get a PHP error regarding 100 levels deep with function recursion

Comment: You may have to do either a strict compare against a string for the recursive case (`if($parent !== "0")`) or just do a simple equality check (`if($parent != 0)`) I updated the answer to use just the simple equality check

Comment: It was a non strict compare plus a couple of bits of javascript you had (+ instead of "." in the array key), works perfect now thanks.

Comment: whoops, been working in js all day and its slipped into mah brain. updated and glad to help

Answer (score -1):

You said there is no [node0].
If you are certain that all nodes are in order (no missing numbers), then you can do something like:

`$i = count($arrayData) //will give you number of nodes`

And you can loop through your array with something like:

```
for ($a=$i, $a>=1; $a--)
{
$b = $arrayData[$a];
$label = $b['label'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but a for loop won't work because it's working upward in a recursive tree grabbing the parents of the node each time... A for loop would recurse the whole array which is not needed. All that is needed is to start at an element and work upward until parent=0 then return the answer

Comment: @J.Doe look again the loop - it starts from end and works upwards to top